# contract.deploymentTransection.wait(1) not working in ethers version 6.4.0

Tags: contract-deployment, etherscan, hardhat, hardhat-deploy, contract-verification

Error is in this line

`const deploymentReceipt = await contract.deploymentTransection.wait(1);`

Entire code I am using to deploy contract and wait

```js
const { ethers, run, network } = require("hardhat");

async function main() {
    const simpleStorage = await ethers.deployContract("SimpleStorage");
    console.log("deploying contract... ");
    await simpleStorage.waitForDeployment();
    const simpleStorageAddress = await simpleStorage.getAddress();

    console.log(`Deployed contract contract to : ${simpleStorageAddress}`);
    if (network.config.chainID === 11155111 && process.env.ETHERSCAN_API_KEY) {
        await simpleStorage.deploymentTransaction.wait(3);
        await verify(simpleStorageAddress, []);
    }
}

async function verify(contractAddress, args) {
    console.log("Verifying Contract");
    try {
        await run("verify:verify", {
            address: contractAddress,
            constructorArguments: args,
        });
    } catch (err) {
        if (err.message.toLowerCase().includes("already verified")) {
            console.log("Already Verified");
        } else {
            console.log(err);
        }
    }
}

main()
    .then(() => process.exit())
    .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
        process. Exit(1);
    });
```

Console

```
$ yarn hardhat run scripts/deploy.js --network sepolia
yarn run v1.22.19
$ "D:\STFU\VS Code\Blockchain\HardHatSimpleStorage\node_modules\.bin\hardhat" run scripts/deploy.js --network sepolia
deploying contract... 
Deployed contract contract to : 0x9D8d3CF1aE495Eb7e4202502f9584cEa0b264690
TypeError: simpleStorage.deploymentTransaction.wait is not a function
    at main (D:\STFU\VS Code\Blockchain\HardHatSimpleStorage\scripts\deploy.js:11:51)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

The thing I want to achieve is to wait for few blocks confirmations.

What to do? Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
 await simpleStorage.deploymentTransaction.wait(3);
```

with

```
await simpleStorage.deployTransaction.wait(6)
```

Comment: it wont work...

Comment: Did you try????

Comment: yes.. i tried everything i know.. as well as what i could find on internet..

it works for earlier versions ethers but not for 6.4.0

Comment: the correct syntax is:
`await simpleStorage.deploymentTransaction().wait(3);`

note the round parenthesis

Answer (score 0):

```
await simpleStorage.deploymentTransaction().wait(3);
```

Note that `deploymentTransaction` is a function call, it requires the round parenthesis.